# Is there a way to interface with / access the IR camera data? (Windows, Surface)

Tags: java, c#, windows

I am currently learning to program in college but I am not yet experienced enough to really know my way around the windows system & how to interact with it. I am working on a side art project that will track my eyes using the internal near IR camera on windows surfaces. I am wondering how to access the data from the camera *specifically the IR camera. There are plenty of sources on how to access the normal front facing camera, but mums the word on the IR camera.

I have looked into Universal Windows Programs, and there seems to be some promise there, but my problem there is that I only know python and Java and UWP requires C#, C++, visualBasic, and JavaScript, of which I have a little experience in JS. Should I just learn some basic C languages and then continue?

Comment: This is a very broad question with many possible answers. Yes UWP is an ideal way to build a Windows application and you can make use of various different APIs in your app. Yes, you'd have to use one of the languages UWP supported languages, I know specifically of C# and C++. If you're familiar with Java, C# is pretty similar and would not be difficult to pick up and use. As far as interacting with the Windows Hello IR camera, I suppose it depends what you'd like to do with it. Windows uses it for security and authentication, so I imagine it's use is protected or limited to some extent.